# continued trouble with classes in python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below code, it is working at first but when I want it to tell me what card number the dealer has it is returning some sort encrypted stuff that I don't understand.

```
[<__main__.Card object at 0x025A4E50>]
```

How do I get this to return the corresponding card number?

Also someone said that I may need to use `__eq__` when comparing things as opposed to the way that I currently am could someone explain why, and also how to use `__eq__` ?

Below is the code for the program that I am trying to get to work, it is a blackjack game.

```
from random import*

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self,suit,number):
        self.suit=suit
        self.number=number

class DeckofCards(object):
    def __init__(self,deck):
        self.deck=deck
        self.shuffledeck=self.shuffle()
        #print(self.shuffledeck)
    def shuffle(self):
        #print('This is shuffle function')
        b=[]
        count=0
        while count<len(self.deck):
            a=randrange(0,len(self.deck))
            if a not in b:
                b.append(self.deck[a])
                count+=1
        return(b)

    def deal(self):
        if len(self.shuffledeck)>0:
            return(self.shuffledeck.pop(0))
        else:
            shuffle(self)
            return(self.shuffledeck.pop(0))
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,name,hand,inout,money,score,bid):
        self.name=name
        self.hand=hand
        self.inout=inout
        self.money=money
        self.score=score
        self.bid=bid
    def __str__(self):
        x = self.name + ":\t"
        x += "Card(s):"
        for y in range(len(self.hand)):
            x +=self.hand[y].face + self.hand[y].suit + " "
        if (self.name != "dealer"):
            x += "\t Money: $" + str(self.money)
        return(x)

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self,deck, player):
        self.player=Player(player,[],True,100,0,0)
        self.dealer=Player("Dealer",[],True,100,0,0)
        self.deck=DeckofCards(deck)
        self.blackjack= False #self.blackjacksearch()
    def blackjacksearch(self):#this is where it says there is an error we moved this because she said it needed to be in this class to get the Getot function 
        if self.player.hand.gettot()==21:
            return True
        else:
            return False    
    def firstround(self):
        self.player.inout=True
        self.player.hand=[]
        self.dealer.hand=[]
        self.dealer.hand.append(DeckofCards.deal(self.deck))
        print('The Dealer has '+str(self.dealer.hand))
        playerbid=int(input('How much would you like to bet?'))
        self.player.bid=playerbid
    def playturn(self):
        while self.player.blackjack!=True or hit=='yes':
            print(self.player.hand)
            a=self.player.hand.append(deal())
            print('The card that you just drew is ' + str(a))
            print(gettot())
            hit=input('Would you like to hit? ')
            if hit=='yes':
                return(self.player.hand.append(deal()))
            else:
                return() #might need to change this
        if self.player.blackjack==True:
            print(self.player.name + " has blackjack ")
        if hit=='no':
            print (self.player.hand.gettot())
    def playdealer(self):
        while self.dealer.hand<17:
            self.dealer.hand.append(deal())
            dealerhand=self.dealer.hand.gettot() #confused
            print(dealerhand)
        if self.dealer.hand==21:
            self.dealer.blackhjack=True
        dealerhand1=self.dealer.hand.gettot()
        print(dealerhand1)

    def gettot(self,hand):
        total=0
        for x in self.hand:
            if x==Card('H','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('D','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('S','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('C','A'):
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            else:
                total+=x
        return(total)

    def playgame(self):
        play = "yes"
        while (play.lower() == "yes"):
            self.firstround()
            self.playturn()
            if self.player.blackjack == True:
                print(self.player.name + " got BLACKJACK! ")
                self.player.money += self.player.bid * 1.5
                print (self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                print("\n")
                self.player.inout = False
            if self.player.score > 21:
                print(self.player.name + " lost with a tot of " + str(self.player.score))
                self.player.money -= self.player.bid
                print (self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                print ("\n\n")
                self.player.inout = False
            self.playdealer()
            if self.dealer.blackjack == True:
                print("Dealer got blackjack, dealer wins\n")
                self.player.money -= self.player.bid
                print("Round\n")
                print("\t",self.dealer)
                print("\t",self.player)
                print("\t Dealer has " + str(self.dealer.score) + ", " + self.player.name + " has " + str(self.player.score))
            elif self.player.inout == True:
                print("Round\n")
                print("\t",self.dealer)
                print("\t",self.player)
                print("\n\t Dealer has " + str(self.dealer.score) + ", " + self.player.name + " has " + str(self.player.score))
                if self.dealer.score > 21:
                    print("\t Dealer lost with a total of " + str(self.dealer.score))
                    self.player.money += self.player.bid
                    print(self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                elif self.player.score > self.dealer.score:
                    print("\t" +self.player.name + " won with a total of " + str(self.player.score))
                    self.player.money += self.player.bid
                    print("\t"+self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                else:
                    print("\t Dealer won with a total of " + str(self.dealer.score))
                    self.player.money -= self.player.bid
                    print("\t"+self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
            else:
                print("Round")
                print("\t",self.dealer)
                print("\t",self.player)
                if self.player.blackjack == False:
                    print("\t "+ self.player.name + " lost" )
                else:
                    print("\t "+self.player.name + " Won!")

            if self.player.money <= 0:
                print(self.player.name + " out of money - out of game ")
                play = "no"
            else:
                play = input("\nAnother round? ")
                print("\n\n")
        print("\nGame over. ")
        print(self.player.name + " ended with " + str(self.player.money) + " dollars.\n")
        print("Thanks for playing.  Come back soon!")



ls= [Card('H','A'),Card('H','2'),Card('H','3'),Card('H','4'),Card('H','5'),Card('H','6'),Card('H','7'),Card('H','8'),Card('H','9'),Card('H','10'),
Card('H','J'),Card('H','Q'),Card('H','K'),
Card('S','A'),Card('S','2'),Card('S','3'),Card('S','4'),Card('S','5'),
Card('S','6'),Card('S','7'),Card('S','8'),Card('S','9'),Card('S','10'),
Card('S','J'),Card('S','Q'),Card('S','K'),
Card('C','A'),Card('C','2'),Card('C','3'),Card('C','4'),Card('C','5'),
Card('C','6'),Card('C','7'),Card('C','8'),Card('C','9'),Card('C','10'),
Card('C','J'),Card('C','Q'),Card('C','K'),
Card('D','A'),Card('D','2'),Card('D','3'),Card('D','4'),Card('D','5'),
Card('D','6'),Card('D','7'),Card('D','8'),Card('D','9'),Card('D','10'),
Card('D','J'),Card('D','Q'),Card('D','K')]

'''tom=Card('Heart','Queen')
print(tom.suit)
print(DeckofCards(ls))
print(ls.suit)'''

def main():
    x = input("Player's name? ")
    blackjack = Game(ls,x)
    blackjack.playgame()
main()
```

Comment: [Python has a `shuffle` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle), no need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the card instead of the list of card objects and give the card a decent `__str__` method to display itself human-readable.  Instead of

```
print(self.player.hand)
```

try this:

```
for card in self.player.hand:
    print(card)
```

and in `class Card` insert this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s%s' % (self.number, self.suit)
```

Concerning your question about the `__eq__`:  An objects `__eq__()` method gets called whenever it gets compared for equality using the `==` operator.  Without such a method, two objects are only equal if they are the same object.  So in your cards you might want to have sth like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.number == other.number and self.suit == other.suit
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `str()` on a `Card` object it calls an inherited `__str__` method which will print out the class name and address of the object.  What you call encrypted is the address of the object.  If you want to print out something different, override the `__str__` method in your class.  For example:

```
class Card(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Card " + self.suit + " " + self.number
```